# Post form to controller in MVC(Orchard)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, controller, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

I have a simple form:

```
<form actions="/module_name/controller_name/function_name" action="GET">
<input type="email" name="email" />
<input type="submit" value="send" />
</form>
```

And I have my controller:

```
[Themed]
    public class controller_name: Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        [AlwaysAccessible]
        public ActionResult function_name()
        {
            int b;
            return new EmptyResult();
        } 
    }
```

The data is only for testing. Because for unknown reason the post only redirect me to the page: localhost/module_name/controller_name/function_name?email=...

Instead of going into controller.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you set up the routing for your module's controller?

Comment: A few comments on this: you should almost never use GET as the action for a form, it's just too dangerous, severely limits the size of your form, and there's just no point. Second, never hard-code the URL of an action. Use the URL helpers instead. This way, if the URL of your action changes for whatever reason, your code will still work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably haven't set up routing for your module. Create a class that looks like this:

```
public class Routes : IRouteProvider {
    public void GetRoutes(ICollection<RouteDescriptor> routes) {
        foreach (var routeDescriptor in GetRoutes())
            routes.Add(routeDescriptor);
    }

    public IEnumerable<RouteDescriptor> GetRoutes() {
        return new[] {
            new RouteDescriptor {
                Priority = 5,
                Route = new Route(
                    "Test", // this is the name of the page url
                    new RouteValueDictionary {
                        {"area", "my_module"}, // this is the name of your module
                        {"controller", "controller_name"},
                        {"action", "function_name"}
                    },
                    new RouteValueDictionary(),
                    new RouteValueDictionary {
                        {"area", "my_module"} // this is the name of your module
                    },
                    new MvcRouteHandler())
            }
        };
    }
}
```